# Does jsoup download CSS, JS, & images

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am learning to write experimental crawler. I am planning to use JSoup. My question is for example if load facebook.com Is JSoup going to download CSS, JS, & Images which are part of that page.

In simple terms
Does JSoup load assets, such as linked style sheet, JS, images etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jsoup` only downloads `html` code that is present in that page. It does not download **JavaScript-generated html**, **linked css or js or images**.

However, for **images** you can extract the `img` tag with `Jsoup`, then download it seperately using `URL` and `Input/OutputStream` in `java`.